# How to send ElectroNeek RPA bot output to Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, rpa

I have made a ElectroNeek RPA bot that scouts the web for a particular piece of data and then I wish to send it to my Telegram. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Let's break up the task in two parts.
First, in order to send anything to yourself at telegram you would need to create a telegram bot and find out your telegram ID. A good tutorial on that is [here](https://khashtamov.com/en/how-to-create-a-telegram-bot-using-python/). Not all of it is necessary. Read from the beginning to the words "Every Update object consists of Message objects." (You would need some basic python skills to implement this).

After you are done, you would have two numbers:

```
bot_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX:AAGs7Rapl-NW00ZoQMs6AP6BfhqvlXXXxXX'
bot_chatID = 'XXXXXXXXX'
```

Second, you would need to create the HTTP request action in your ElectroNeek flow like so:

[image]

The URL property should be a string that is comprised of variables obtained in step one, telegram URL and your message, like so:

```
'https://api.telegram.org/bot' + bot_token + '/sendMessage?chat_id=' + bot_chatID + '&text=' + your_variable
```

where "your_variable" is the variable you would like to send yourself on Telegram.